# Local Storage to change

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am using a script to load a thumbnail through local storage, but I would also like to have the body background change to this image?

Can anyone help/point me in the right direction? I've tired:

```
$('body').css('background-image','url(localStorage.img)');
```

I've made a Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ma9ic/NRDZk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the event function to:

```
$('body').css('background-image','url(' + e.target.result + ')');
```

or use the storage:

```
$('body').css('background-image','url(' + localStorage.img + ')');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/heecD/

Comment: Thanks Rafael, been staring at this one for a while !

Answer (score 2):

there is a error in you code

```
$('body').css('background-image','url('+localStorage.img+')');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the localstorage as variable not constant like:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + localStorage.img + ')');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/NRDZk/5/